# Once I had a chest full of treasures

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Once I had a chest full of treasures.
>   The only thing left of it is the cage where I kept them.
>   I have no money anymore. Not that I need any.
>   I am used as a base to build things.
>
> I didn't leave my room for years.
>   I feel in my bones that it won't change.
>   For some I am an armour.
>   For some I am a coat hanger for all they are.

**Who/What am I?**

**EDIT**: Added second stanza to narrow the question

Comment: This one seems a little too broad.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - if the comment above reaches +3 (if others agree) I'll add some more specific clues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> A skeleton.

Once I had a chest full of treasures.

> The internal organs.

The only thing left of it is the cage where I kept them.

> The rib cage.

I have no money anymore. Not that I need any.

> Not quite sure about it. Dead people don't need money.

I am used as a base to build things.

> "A skeleton" is used as a term for it.

I didn't leave my room for years.
I feel in my bones that it won't change.

> You were inside the body.

For some I am an armour.
For some I am a coat hanger for all they are.

> Exoskeleton and endoskeleton.

Comment: The "money" part refered exactly to what you pointed.

Comment: dead people need a gold coin to pay Charon the ferryman of Hades